# UWP keep binding when parent object is changed

Tags: c#, binding, uwp

If I have an object e.g. a Person object with two strings name and email address, have an instance of the object called user and have bound the properties like so

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=User.Name, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>

<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=User.Email, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
```

Is there a way to keep the binding when setting user to a new instance of the person class?

The reason is that I am planning to do this with objects that have a very large number of property's and are returned from an api so I wanted to avoid having to replace each property individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bindings.Update()
```

called after object change should do the work